# Stuck on git commit window

Tags: git

I am stuck on this window. i did a `git add -a` just before and then a `git commit` in git-cmd.exe .
How can i get out of here? i wrote my commit message and press enter and nothing happened.

I'm affraid to just close the window and i find nothing on internet, the official site say nothing about how to validate a commit corectly.

[image: git commit window]

Answer (score 15):

You are in a vi editor.

In order to save and exit from vi you need to do this:

To save the changes:    <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>:wq</kbd>
                    Or: <kbd>ZZ</kbd>
To discard the changes: <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>:q!</kbd>

(Look on the button of the screenshot how to exit - ***`the last line`***)

[image]

Comment: the esc zz cmd did work. thank you all for your help

Comment: oh geez I was forgetting the colon in front of wq

Answer (score 4):

This happened because you didn't send any message on your commit (using the parameter -m, example: git commit -m "Your commit message").
The default behaviour when you do this is to open the default text editor from Git, which in this case is VIM.
If you want to change it, just simply follow the instructions in here: https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are in vi/vim. Try the esc key to exit insert mode, and then ZZ to save and exit.