# Mac Terminal "trapped" by git and won't let me use bash commands

Tags: git, terminal, git-commit

So, I was experimenting with Git for the first time and I decided to add a commit message. I used this code:

```
git commit
```

....which led me to a commenting screen of some sort. I put in my comment, hit enter, and absolutely nothing happened. The terminal isn't accepting any commands, and it doesn't even look like it's the same interface anymore. How do I exit this?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs In the new terminal or the trapped one? If it's the new one, absolutely nothing: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/VwVlG)

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs yeah, I saw vim in the header, so I tried that, and I got something on the bottom saying `E490: No fold found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stuck on git commit window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782525/stuck-on-git-commit-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Check Your Editor

Check what editor your shell is passing as an environment variable in a new terminal with:

```
echo "EDITOR: $EDITOR"
echo "VISUAL: $VISUAL"
```

You should also check what values Git itself might be using in a global or local *.gitconfig* file as well. Specifically:

```
git config core.editor
git config gui.editor
```

### Git Defaults to *vi*

Git uses the modal editor *vi* by default. If you're using anything other than vi or vim per the output above, then follow the commands for that editor. Otherwise, try one of the following:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>ZZ
- <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>:wq<kbd>RETURN</kbd>

to write and exit your buffer in vi/vim.

Answer (score 4):

[Todd A. Jacobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301972/todd-a-jacobs) already told you how to exit `vi/vim`.

If you wish to prevent this thing to happen next time, try:

```
git commit -m 'your commit message'
```

to not use an editor at all for your commit message.

Comment: This is not what OP question is about

Comment: Ok, sorry. my fault, the question was obviously "how to exit vim". I just gave an example for preventing this to happen (when not familiar with vi/vim).

Comment: Being asked to review this, i can only say: I think this is a valid additional answer helping OP in the future. @cecky please keep offering "out of the box" answers.